# Is there a better way to get users information and their manager for a specific MemberOf Group in Graph API Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a better way to get users' information and their manager for a specific MemberOf Group in Graph API in Powershell? I have written below, it works but doesn't seem to be the best way to do this. I am new to this so please take it easy on me!

Ideally, I would like ALL fields from the Get-MgUser with the user's Manager and the specific MgUserMemberOf group I am searching for at the end of the CSV export, but not sure if it is possible.

```
if (Get-InstalledModule Microsoft.Graph) {
    # Connect to MS Graph    $appid = 'BLAH' $tenantid = 'BLAH' $secret = 'BLAH'

    $body = @{
        Grant_Type    = 'client_credentials'
        Scope         = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
        Client_Id     = $appid
        Client_Secret = $secret
    }

    $connection = Invoke-RestMethod `
        -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token `
        -Method POST `
        -Body $body $token = $connection.access_token Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token

    ### Comment out below to use the production version of Azure AD

    Select-MgProfile -Name 'beta'

    $users = Get-MgUser -Filter "startsWith(DisplayName, 'Joe Bloggs')"
    foreach($Id in $users) {
        $MemberOf = Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserId $CurrentID | Where-Object { $_.AdditionalProperties['displayName'] -like '*VIP*' } | Select-Object id, @{E = { $_.additionalProperties['displayName'] } }
        $UserManager = Get-MgUserManager -UserId $CurrentID | Select-Object id, @{E = { $_.additionalProperties['displayName'] } }
        $Result = "$($users.Id) , ""$($users.DisplayName)"", ""$($UserManager.'$_.additionalProperties[''displayName'']')"", ""$($MemberOf.'$_.additionalProperties[''displayName'']')"""
        Write-Host $Result
        Add-Content 'C:\Temp\Result.csv' $Result
    }
}
```

Current Export

```
00000000-56fa-4638-9ff6-1dc85d3c9735 , "DISPLAY NAME", "MANAGER", "Member Of GROUP"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is very confusing but I think what you're looking for is something similar to this. For sure you should be building your CSV manually, you can create objects and the pass them through the pipeline to `Export-Csv` to parse them for you. In both cases, you can use `-ExpandProperty` instead of calling `Get-MgUserManager` and `Get-MgUserMemberOf` separately.

```
if (Get-Module Microsoft.Graph -ListAvailable) {
    $params = @{
        Uri    = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token"
        Method = 'POST'
        Body   = @{
            Grant_Type    = 'client_credentials'
            Scope         = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
            Client_Id     = $appid
            Client_Secret = $secret
        }
    }

    $connection = Invoke-RestMethod @params

    Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $connection.access_token
    Select-MgProfile -Name 'beta'

    $getMgUserSplat = @{
        Filter         = "startsWith(DisplayName, 'Joe Bloggs')"
        ExpandProperty = 'manager', 'memberOf'
    }

    Get-MgUser @getMgUserSplat | ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Id          = $_.Id
            DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
            Manager     = $_.Manager.AdditionalProperties.displayName
            MemberOf    = $_.memberOf.AdditionalProperties.displayName -like '*VIP*'
        }
    } | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\Result.csv' -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: Thank you I have it working from the example above

Comment: Does this still work (Aug, 2023)? I get an error about `Get-MgUser : The result of parsing $expand contained at least 2 items, but the maximum allowed is 1.` and that seems consistent with the current docs.