# Convert C# to powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell

Is there a way where I can convert the C# code to powershell script? I want the below code in powershell script. But since I am a newbie to powershell I am not able to convert it. Is there any utitlity to do it?

```
var tenantId = tId;
var clientId = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[5];
var clientSecret = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[6];
var audience = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[2] + "/";
var domainUrl = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[7];

 using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(domainUrl);
var httpRequestBody = "{ \"client_id\": \"" + clientId + "\", \"client_secret\": \"" + clientSecret + "\" , \"audience\": \"" + audience + "\"," +
" \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\", \"TenantId\": \"" + tenantId + "\"}";
var jsonContent = new StringContent(httpRequestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
string relativeUrl = $"oauth/token";
var httpResponse = httpClient.PostAsync(relativeUrl, jsonContent).Result;
if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
var jsonString = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString.ToString());
var accessToken = obj["access_token"].ToString();
return accessToken;
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Error generating token.");
Environment.Exit((int)ExitCode.TokenError);
}
```

Comment: Rather than "converting" from C# to PowerShell, you're better off _learning_ PowerShell properly, and _rewriting_ the C# program into PowerShell from first principles, rather than "translating".

Comment: The first part of this answer has how its translated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74296649/15339544 // much easier would be to use the MSAL.PS module to get a token

Comment: if the goal to call this code from powershell, maybe better to use something like Cake.build: https://cakebuild.net/. Where you can use almost all c# functionality and then call it from powershell

Comment: @Jess, many will suggest that this is not a question suitable for SO based on https://stackoverflow.com/help. Don't be surprised if there are downvotes and close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
$tenantId = tId;
$clientId = [System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[5];
$clientSecret = [System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[6];
$audience = [System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[2] + "/";
$domainUrl = [System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[7];

$httpClient = [System.Net.WebClient.HttpClient]::new();
 
$httpClient.BaseAddress = [System.Uri]::new($domainUrl);
$httpRequestBody = "{ \"client_id\": \"" + clientId + "\", \"client_secret\": \"" + clientSecret + "\" , \"audience\": \"" + audience + "\"," +  " \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\", \"TenantId\": \"" + tenantId + "\"}";

$jsonContent = [System.Net.Http.StringContent]::new($httpRequestBody, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8, "application/json");
$relativeUrl = $"oauth/token";
$httpResponse = $httpClient.PostAsync($relativeUrl, $jsonContent).Result;
if ($httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   $jsonString = $httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   $obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString.ToString());
   $accessToken = obj["access_token"].ToString();
   return $accessToken;
}
else
{
   Write-Host("Error generating token.");
   [System.Environment]::Exit(12345);
}
```