# Is there a way to convert form-data to x-www-form-urlencoded format, while POSTing an api call from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am writing powershell script in VSCode.

I keep running into the stated issues, when trying to convert the form-data to x-www-form-urlencoded format.

I have a form data as below:

```
$formData = @{
    'grant_type' = 'password'
    'scope' = 'xyz'
    'client_id' = 'xyzAPIClient'
    'client_secret' = 'xyzabcdef'
    'username' = 'user1@xyz.com'
    'password' = 'password1'
}
```

I tried to convert it to *x-www-form-urlencoded* format, in order to use it as below (to post a request to the server):

```
$formUrlEncoded = $formData | ForEach-Object {"$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)"} -join '&'
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiEndPoint -Method Post -Body $formUrlEncoded -Headers $headers
```

I run into the below issue

```
ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the "-join" value of type "System.String" to type 
"System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At C:\Automation\automation-scripts\automation-getToken.ps1:15 char:31
+ ... oded = $formData | ForEach-Object {"$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)"} -join '&'
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

I am new to powershell and I couldn't understand what is causing this issue. Could somebody help

Comment: enclose your expression in `(...)` otherwise `-join` is binded as a argument of `ForEach-Object`. `($formData | ForEach-Object {"$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)"}) -join '&'`. As aside, are you sure you need to do this? `-Body` can take a hashtable as you have it right now, no need for joining its key / value pairs. Try `-Body $formData`

Comment: Thank you! Like you said, I tried by passing just the $formData hashtable in -Body and it did work.

Comment: Glad it was helpful ;) it was for a Graph token right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain the error you're getting, this error happens because PowerShell is assuming that `-join` is being passed as argument of `ForEach-Object` this is why you need to wrap your expression with the [grouping operator `( )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--), basically to, as explained in the documentation, "*let output from a command participate in an expression*". In addition, hashtables are not enumerable by default in PowerShell, you must use the [`.GetEnumerator()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.system-collections-ienumerable-getenumerator?view=net-8.0#system-collections-hashtable-system-collections-ienumerable-getenumerator):

```
$formData = @{
    'grant_type'    = 'password'
    'scope'         = 'xyz'
    'client_id'     = 'xyzAPIClient'
    'client_secret' = 'xyzabcdef'
    'username'      = 'user1@xyz.com'
    'password'      = 'password1'
}
$formUrlEncoded = ($formData.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" }) -join '&'
$formUrlEncoded

# Outputs:
# username=user1@xyz.com&client_id=xyzAPIClient&password=password1&scope=xyz&grant_type=password&client_secret=xyzabcdef
```

Taking a step back, the [`-Body` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.4#-body) from `Invoke-RestMethod` takes `IDIctionary` as input and already knows how to deal with instances implementing the interface, so it is very likely that you don't need to join the key / value pairs to form the url-encoded-string.

In summary, it is likely that this should work (as it becomes evident you're trying to get a token from the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?tabs=http#4-request-an-access-token), see the examples from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77614905/15339544v) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74296649/15339544)):

```
$formData = @{
    'grant_type'    = 'password'
    'scope'         = 'xyz'
    'client_id'     = 'xyzAPIClient'
    'client_secret' = 'xyzabcdef'
    'username'      = 'user1@xyz.com'
    'password'      = 'password1'
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiEndPoint -Method Post -Body $formData -Headers $headers
```

---

Side note, in case you do need to form the url-encoded-string, using the [`HttpUtility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=net-8.0) APIs can be useful here:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$query = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString('')
$formData.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { $query[$_.Key] = $_.Value }

# if you need URL encoded:
$query.ToString()
# username=user1%40xyz.com&client_id=xyzAPIClient&password=password1&scope=xyz&grant_type=password&client_secret=xyzabcdef

# if you need URL decoded:
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($query.ToString())
# username=user1@xyz.com&client_id=xyzAPIClient&password=password1&scope=xyz&grant_type=password&client_secret=xyzabcdef
```

Comment: +1 for the referring to the standard parsers. Besides, if you DIY, I would recommend to actually encode the keys and values, something like: `"$([uri]::EscapeDataString($_.Key))=$([uri]::EscapeDataString($_.Value))"`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Hashtable, you cannot access it looping that way

Specifically: it's a "single object", though it's made of multiple values. It's like piping a string: it's not going to iterate through each character.

This should work
`$formUrlEncoded = ($formdata.keys | ForEach-Object { "$_=$($formdata.$_)" }) -join '&'`